# Give a probability distribution p(x), how can one sample according to the distribution q(x) = f(x)p(x)\Z

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, sampling, monte-carlo

Given a probability distribution $p(x)$ with x being a continuous random variable, how can one sample according to the distribution $q(x) $$=$$ \frac{f(x)p(x)}{Z}$ where $Z$$=$$\int f(x)p(dx)$ is a normalizing constant.

Comment: Please provide your efforts to solve this sum.

Comment: I really don't have a clear idea of how to sample from q(x). Since computing q(x) for all x looks computationally very expensive, I was hoping a method like MCMC could help here. But I am not knowledgeable enough about MCMC to know how it could (or could not ) possibly be used here. Any clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) on $q$?

Comment: @parsiad I did not know about inverse transform sampling. I took a quick look at the wiki. Then my question would be how to compute the inverse CDF of q(x)? Is that doable for any distribution?

Comment: @erfaun: I wrote a more detailed answer below, but here's a short version: sample a uniform random number $u$ in $(0, 1)$ and compute $F^{-1}(u)$ where $F$ is the CDF of $q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Proposition (Inverse transform sampling)**.
Let $F$ be a CDF and define
$$
G(u) = \inf \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \colon F(x) \geq u \right\}.
$$
Given a uniform random variable $U$ on the unit interval $(0, 1)$, $G(U)$ has CDF $F$.

In other words, *if we have a uniform [RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation), we can sample from any target distribution*.

*Proof*.
If $F$ has an inverse, then $G = F^{-1}$ and hence
$$
  \mathbb{P}(G(U) \leq x)
= \mathbb{P}(F^{-1}(U) \leq x)
= \mathbb{P}(U \leq F(x))
= F(x).
$$

The case in which $F$ does not admit an inverse is more involved (see [1]).

In your case, $F$ is just the CDF of the random variable with PDF $q$.

[1] *Walsh, John B.*, Knowing the odds. An introduction to probability, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 139. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-8532-1/hbk). xvi, 421 p. (2012). [ZBL1270.60004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1270.60004).